# Accessing cells of a dataframe using column names and row names as input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to take input of the column name and row name from the user and print the intersection of these as output.
Python code used:
here rm is a dataframe

```
Uid=input("Enter user id")
Iid=input("Enter item id:")
print(rm.loc[Uid][Iid])
```

here Userid is stored in column and Itemid in row

sample dataframe being used:

userID    132560    132561    132564    132572    132583    132584  \
0  U1001  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111
1  U1002  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000
2  U1003  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385
3  U1004  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000
4  U1005  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333

```
 132594    132608    132609    ...       135081    135082    135085  \
```

0  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111    ...     1.111111  1.111111  0.000000
1  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000    ...     1.400000  1.400000  1.000000
2  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385    ...     1.615385  1.615385  1.615385
3  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000    ...     1.875000  1.875000  1.875000
4  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333    ...     1.333333  1.333333  1.333333

```
 135086    135088    135104    135106    135108    135109      mean
```

0  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111  1.111111
1  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000  1.000000  1.400000  1.400000  1.400000
2  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385  1.615385
3  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000  2.000000  1.875000  1.875000  1.875000
4  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1.333333  1

I even tried with 
    rm.loc[Uid,Iid]

but,that gives me an error that that given userid is not present when it actually is.
Please help me out. :(

Comment: Something like ?`rm.loc[:,'Uid'].loc[Iid]`

Comment: are your user id and item id string or integer? If they are integers, you will have to first convert the Uid and Iid to int because input returns string

Comment: But,my userid has to be a string.. Does Dataframe.loc[ ][ ] not take a string,I mean as the column and row labels.Is it necessary for it be an integer?

Comment: If you post your df.head(), it would make it more clear to understand the exact problem

Comment: I've added it to th question

Comment: This same rm.loc[][] works fine when indexed with already specified column names and row names but,gives error with input

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, not an exact dupe plus both values are columns. Got more clear after df.head

Comment: @Ankita Das, Given that both uid and iid are columns, direct indexing won't work as it assumes the first value to be the row index. You have to use df.loc[df['userID']==Uid, Iid]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158558/discussion-between-ankita-das-and-vaishali).